# Xcode ignores the breakpoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, breakpoints

While working on an old objectiv-C project, in order to prepare an update for the appStore, I hit this problem: X**code totally ignores my breakpoints.**
I can see by using `NSLog()` that the code is executed as expected, but it doesn't stop as it should at breakpoints.

I am using OS X Version 10.11.4 and Xcode Version 7.3.1.

I have seen a number of posts on the net about this issue, but none of the tricks proposed fixed my problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're not in release mode/scheme?

Comment: I don't think so. But how can I check that to be safe?

Comment: Press "command + shift + , ", I think, and you'll see.

Comment: Also another place to check is on the blue color breakpoint  button in Xcode. Press command + shift + y and bring up the console. The console's top bar has a breakpoint blue button. If that is greyed out, then it will skip break points.

Comment: It brings a window called: Device Information. Since I suspect we have a different keyboard I tried another key combination, which brings the Edit Scheme dialog (this is probably what you mean). But how do I know from there the mode/scheme I am currently using? I can see, looking at various places in the dialog, a field called "Build Configuration" sometimes set to "Debug" others to "Release". But I still don't know which I am currently using. Anyway I tried to flip that to the other position to see if it makes a difference, and that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: About the 2nd suggestion, your key combination does not work for me, but I see what you mean. The buttons are all blue, not greyed out, so this is not the issue either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114899/discussion-between-blackflam3-and-michel).

Comment: was there any solution to this problem? I'm still having it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i faced the same problem.
 Just follow these steps -

1 - `DELETE` the app from `device`.
2 - Click on `x-code-> preference -> Location -> Derived Data`
3 - `force quit x-code`.
4 - `delete` tha `Derived Data`.
5 - Do `Empty trash` also.
6 - start `x-code` project .